# bootstrap navbar com erro

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

Boa Tarde povo, seguinte, coloquei um navbar no meu projeto na parte mobile ele da pau, clico nas barrinhas o menu aparece e depois some, sozinho, alguém já passou por isso? segue link do meu projeto

http://renovetintas.com.br/demo/

se alguém puder me ajudar, eu agradeço!

Comment: Forneça um código javascript, html e css da parte que você está realizando a parte responsiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem código não da para te ajudar muito.

Mas seu erro está nessa tag

```
<div class="navbar-collapse header celm collapse in" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="z-index: 9999;" aria-expanded="true">
```

Repare que mesmo quando ela está aberta .in a classe `.collapse` permanece no elemento e faz ele desaparecer. Se vc tirar o `.collapse` quando ela estiver com o `.in` ele vai funcionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Repare que quando ela fica com o `.collapse` a nav recebe um `display:none !important`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito Obrigado funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: @MarcosC.Anzolin que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita.